# Multi row in table by using jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have a table for students and their grades by using the jinja2 template.
[image: table design]

```
 
<table>
<tr>
<the>Student Name</th>
<the>Course</th>
<the>Grad</th>
<tr class="">
   {% for student in students %}
   <td rowspan="3">
    student.name
   </td>
<td>student.course</td>
  <td>student.grd</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Brief Explanation

1. Enclose variables inside double brackets (`{{` and `}}`);
2. The tag `the` is actually `th` by html standards (also, the closing tags have to be the same as the opening ones);
3. Remodel your data structure: for instance, courses can be an array of objects or dictionaries in a student object/dictionary, so it can be iterated over;
4. The `rowspan` html attribute needs to be the size of the courses because it determines how many rows to be spanned;
5. The `rowspan` attribute has to be declared once per table data (`td`) on each row for this case, which is on the name of the student, as you already noticed.

#### Code

You have to change the square brackets (`[` and `]`) accessor to the dot (`.`) operator, if you are using a standard instance class object instead of a dictionary.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
    
    {% for student in students %}
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{student['courses']|length)}}">{{student['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{student['courses'][0]['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{student['courses'][0]['grd']}}</td>
    </tr>
        {% for course in student['courses'][1:] %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{course['name']}}</td>
            <td>{{course['grd']}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

#### Sample Jinja2 Rendered Output

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Anonymous</td>
        <td>CS</td>
        <td>90</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>NC</td>
          <td>60</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Elephant</td>
        <td>MATH</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>APPLIED MATH</td>
        <td>90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Data sample for testing

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Anonymous",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "grd": "90",
                    "name": "CS"
                },
                {
                    "grd": "60",
                    "name": "NC"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "name": "Elephant",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "grd": "100",
                    "name": "MATH"
                },
                {
                    "grd": "90",
                    "name": "APPLIED MATH"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

<sub>Technically, a dictionary in Python is an object but I discriminated them for explanation purposes.</sub>

#### Reading recommendation

- See [W3Schools' tutorial on rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_td_rowspan.asp);
- See [Jinja's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables);
- See [W3Schools' standard tags list](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/).